# Error: xml textView in a gridlayout is null

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am having an issue on the last line of the code. It says  "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference"
The grid is supposedly null. I see that when I print it but it shouldn't be.

Also, I have a 4x4 grid full of textView's which is what the grid numbers are, then eventually boxID to make it an ID. I am not sure if I am doing that part correctly.

Can anyone help? This is the code where the last line gives me the null error:

```
// Displays the numbers to the grid
public void display_grid() {
    TextView pointView = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text));
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            String grid_num = "grid" + x + "_" + y;
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(Gameplay.grid[x][y]));

            // Turning the space of the grid to an ID so it can be displayed
            int boxID = getResources().getIdentifier(grid_num, "id", getPackageName());
            ((TextView) findViewById(boxID)).setText(String.valueOf(Gameplay.grid[x][y]));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the XML code for the grid layout with textboxes. I know it is a lot but in case it is needed it is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Gameplay">

<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="339dp"
    android:layout_height="249dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.523"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.81">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid1_1"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid1_2"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid1_3"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid0_1"
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid0_2"
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid0_3"
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid2_0"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid2_1"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid2_2"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid2_3"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid3_0"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid3_1"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid3_2"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid3_3"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_row="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid1_0"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid0_0"
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="0" />
</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: What are the ids of your text views?

Comment: @Cheticamp I added the xml info

Comment: Looks OK. The question now is what is that `findViewById()` looking at? I don't think it's the layout that you posted. Where is that code?

Comment: @Cheticamp Is findViewById( ) supposed to be assigned to a specific place? I have two XML files. The activity_main file and another called game_screen. Do I have to assign findViewById( ) to the one I am calling, which is game_screen.xml? I am just using the built in libraries for findViewById

Comment: It looks like `display_grid` is a member of an activity. If so, `findViewById()` would look in the XML associated with the activity. If your ids are not in the activity, you will need a reference to the inflated XML file and the would look like `view.findViewById()`.

Comment: @Cheticamp I am not sure if you are familiar with the game 2048 but that is what I am recreating. When the user makes a move the display grid screen will be called to update the grid of numbers that is shown to the user. How can I associate another XML into the file? or is it only possible to do one? I added "view." to findViewById( ), but I am still not sure how to make that direct to the game_screen.xml file (instead of the default activity_main.xml file,)  which has the boxID that I am trying to change. Sorry if this does not make too much sense, this is my first android studio project

Comment: For learning, I suggest that you start by trying to find an explicit id in your layout. An id such as `R.id.grid0_0` and move on from there once you are successful. There are many examples available online that you can model.

Comment: @Cheticamp No matter what I try to change, if it is on the game_screen.xml file and not the activity_main one, it will not work because it says it null. So it must not be recognizing that it exists in game_screen. I think if I figure out why that is I can fix the problem I just do not know how